# Please explain how to configure a satellite for btc payments with blockstream via space

Tags: transactions, payment, blockstream, blockstream-satellite

Blockstream has its own satellites in the space orbit, right. So , as I understand, there must be very special requirements met for your satellite to be able to do transactions through space. Not every type of satellit is able to fulfill this...

Which are the exact requirements?  I was told that you need:
- satellite brand / exact type of the satellite
- exact coordinates/communication channel
- receiver box name/type of receiver box

What does one need precisely and how should you configure it?

Is any wallet capable of this sort of tx, or if not, which one is?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand the question.  It sounds like maybe you are mixing up *satellite* (the object in space that sends the signals) with *satellite dish* (the antenna on the ground that you use to receive the signals).

Comment: Have you already read https://github.com/Blockstream/satellite#hardware-requirements?

Comment: There is no blockstream dedicated satellite, no. It’s piggybacked on TV transmissions. You can’t transmit anything to it as a result, it is receive only.